# How can I serialize Petrel Property in my Custom DataSource and load it back?

Tags: ocean, petrel

I am not very "fluent" with Ocean serialization . 
Can I serialize an entire Petrel Property (Properties, Grids or any other Petrel/Ocean's objects) into my custom DataSource? Will I be able to load it back? 
Is there any good practice/pattern to do that? 
Some code sample would be welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an established DataSource already?  The persistence back end (SQL? XML?) used by your DataSource dictates how data is stored.  Any data you want to persist through the DataSource must be converted to your back-end's format.

Note that there is no such thing as "Ocean serialization" with DataSources - you (and only you) are in complete control of the DataSource.  Usually, you are actually providing it as a service to Ocean, so that it, given a Droid, can resolve one of **your** objects (be they e.g. custom domain objects, workstep argument packages or seismic attribute argument packages).

Now, from your question, it sounds like you are seeking to store deep copies of the Petrel data you mention.  Is this **really** the case?  If so, I'm afraid you'll need to make your own data structures representing this data, mirroring what you can read out through Ocean's APIs.

If what you really want to store is a **weak reference** to the Petrel data (implementing IIdentifiable), you'll want to persist the contents of each object's Droid - a much simpler task.

Then, when your persisted data is resolved from your DataSource, you'd rebuild the Droid(s), which can then be resolved themselves (using some other DataSource but your own), resulting in a regular strong .NET reference to the object - assuming of course that this data is present in the currently loaded project.

The SimpleDataSourceExample in the Ocean SDK demonstrates a simple DataSource backed by a .dat file using  BinaryFormatter.  This is relatively trivial to modify to other back-ends.  I strongly recommend XML over BinaryFormatter, but if you intend to store considerable amounts of bulk data, you should consider a database.   At Blueback Reservoir, XML has served our needs very well.

A minor caveat: make sure that the objects you store in your DataSource implement IDisposable (as well as IIdentifiable), to free resources in the DataSource.